# MSAL Azure ADb2c Throwing error after resetting the password and launching the application in Native Android

Tags: android, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I was integrating azure AdB2c for my native android application, I have used `SignInSignUp` and
`passwordReset` userFlow for my current Application. Currently When I'm resetting the password, the password gets changed and redirect to app as expected, but when tries to relaunch the application after some time,MSAL is throwing out an exception ,which is `messagecom.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalUiRequiredException: AADB2C90088: The provided grant has not been issued for this endpoint. Actual Value : B2C_1_SignInSignUp and Expected Value : B2C_1_PasswordReset` . How can I handle during Such situation?

Answer (score 0):

You are using seperate password reset and sign in/sign up flows. This means once the user performs password reset, the tokens are issued for the password reset policy. Later, once the access token expires, the refresh token is used to get a new access token. In this call, you pass in an account object (password reset), but perform the call against the sign in/up authority. This causes an error as the refresh token in the password reset account object can only be used against the password reset authority (policy).

To solve this, you can use the combined sign up/in/password reset journey.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow#self-service-password-reset-recommended

Comment: Suri -  I'm currently  using  **Sign up and sign** in` and  **Password reset** user flow for my application. when user click on `Forgot Password`, the error code `AADB2C90118` is handled and call  **B2C_1_PasswordReset** authority and user can create new password and redirect to the application .  I have referred the mentioned document, and  was handling the `password Reset` as mentioned. can you just mentioned how to handle such situation, with help of a sample?

Comment: You are not using the the flow from the link, because you get AADB2C90118 and that is the legacy method. You need to use one user flow for sign in/up/password-reset. Follow the doc once more. You should not be using a policy for **just** Password Reset at all.

Comment: Suri - Thanks for the Update. I will refer the document and implement as required.